# Cannot find module 'react-redux'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, react-redux

I am using webpack to put my codebase together and I continue to get the error message "Cannot find module 'react-redux'".

I have checked my node-modules folder and it is indeed in there. My code is the correct spelling. I have already deleted my entire node modules folder and reinstalled them.

I've even gone so far as to install react-redux (and necessarily, both react and redux individually) globally. I'm not sure what I thought this would accomplish, but at this point I am desperate.

If any other information/code is relevant, just leave a comment, I'll be watching this all day (11.14.16)

**code in question**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as some from 'lodash/collection/some';
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "init": "npm install & bower install & typings install & wait; echo Init done.",
    "build-css": "gulp styles",
    "build-js": "webpack",
    "prod:build": "ENV=prod webpack && ENV=prod gulp rev",
    "prod:commit": "git rm $(git ls-files --deleted 2.0/assets/scripts/ 2.0/assets/styles/) && git add 2.0/assets/scripts/app*.js 2.0/assets/styles/main*.css rev-manifest.json && git commit -m 'prod assets'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "basscss-sass": "^4",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "corejs-typeahead": "^0.11.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.3.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^2",
    "imagesloaded": "^3",
    "jquery": "^1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.14.0",
    "lodash": "^3",
    "magnific-popup": "^1.1",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "^3.1",
    "modularized-normalize-scss": "^4",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-truncate": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "signals": "^1.0.0",
    "url-parse": "^1.0.5",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-pixrem": "^1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-all": "^0.8",
    "gulp-sass": "^2",
    "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "ng-annotate-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

var config = {
  env: (process.env.ENV || "dev") // `prod` or `dev`
}

plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: (config.env === "prod" ? '"production"' : '"development"')
    }
  }),
  new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
  ),
  // Until webpack@2 we need this. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/198
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({"window.jQuery": "jquery"})
];

if (config.env === "prod") {
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console: true
      },
      comments: false
    })
  );
}

module.exports = {
  entry: "./2.0/src/scripts/app.ts",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/2.0/src/scripts",
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['ts-loader']},
      { test: /mousewheel\.js/, loader: 'imports?define=>false'} // See https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/371
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: [__dirname+'/bower_components'],
    extensions: ["", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  devtool: (config.env === "dev" ? "eval" : false)
};
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "dependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
    "classnames": "registry:dt/classnames#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "fullcalendar": "registry:dt/fullcalendar#1.6.1+20160317120654",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160417213236",
    "lodash": "registry:dt/lodash#3.10.0+20160720001309",
    "mcustomscrollbar": "registry:dt/mcustomscrollbar#2.8.2+20160604165202",
    "moment": "registry:dt/moment#2.8.0+20160316155526",
    "moment-node": "registry:dt/moment-node#2.11.1+20160511043338",
    "react": "registry:dt/react#0.14.0+20160602151522",
    "react-bootstrap": "registry:dt/react-bootstrap#0.0.0+20160713061231",
    "react-dom": "registry:dt/react-dom#0.14.0+20160412154040",
    "react-redux": "registry:dt/react-redux#4.4.0+20160724070751",
    "redux": "registry:dt/redux#3.5.2+20160703092728",
    "tooltipster": "registry:dt/tooltipster#0.0.0+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include your Webpack config, too.

Comment: Hang on - is your error coming from Webpack, or the TypeScript loader? And if the latter, do you have the typings for your libraries installed?

Comment: I am gettting the error from Webpack. I do have the typings installed.

I've edited my post to include my webpack.config.js and typings.json